# Duda de concepto para hacer tests

Tags: c++, terminal, ejecutar

Resulta que en mi clase de programación los profesores nos han comentado que cuando tu tienes un programa en C++ con registros, arrays, strings y eso (no es muy avanzado, estoy en primero de carrera).
Pues resulta que tu cuando compilas el programa y lo ejecutas puedes meter pruebas automáticamente.

Ej: 
Digamos que tengo un programa que te hace sumas, pues tu puedes desde un archivo poner las pruebas que quieres que te haga, ejemplo(2+2,2+4,5+6,7+3...) y así no tener que estar tu desde la terminal mentiendolo a mano, alguíen me podría decir como es. Es para algo más difícil que lo de las sumas, pero no se como se llaman las pruebas esas ni nada.

Porque digamos que yo tengo que hacer que mediante una frase te la guarde y te busque cosas, entonces quiero meter muchas frases de golpe o cosas así.

No sé como explicarlo del todo, porque yo tampoco sé lo que es 100%. He intentado poner el máximo número de ejemplos.

Comment: Debes programar las pruebas.

Comment: Tenes que hacer algo que simule lo que haria el usuario. Por ejemplo tomar los datos de un archivo de texto y pasarlos a la funcion que queres probar, y comprobar los resultados.

Comment: vale, pero como se hace eso, quiero decir para yo poner todas las pruebas en un documento y ejecutándolo con la terminal que me lo haga, es que no sé los comando ni nada

Comment: "*en mi clase de programación los profesores nos han comentado que cuando tu tienes un programa en C++ con registros, arrays, strings y eso (… ). Pues resulta que tu cuando compilas el programa y lo ejecutas puedes meter pruebas automáticamente*" falso. No se a que pruebas se refieren, pero en C++ si quieres que el programa haga algo, debes programarlo tú… nada es automático.

Comment: Pueden referirse a test unitarios que puedes realizar si utilizas una herramienta de compilacion como CMake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los algoritmos en programación son traicioneros... cualquier cambio que hagas en el código puede tener efectos impredecibles que provocan regresiones, es decir, que cosas antes funcionaban ahora han dejado de hacerlo.

Para mitigar estos efectos es habitual que se programen pruebas o tests que validen los diferentes componentes de un programa.

En el caso de C++, existen varias librerías pensadas para este menester:

- [Google test](https://github.com/google/googletest)
- [CppUnit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/)
- [Boost.Test](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html)
- [CxxTest](https://cxxtest.com/)
- [Qt Test](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttest-index.html)
- ...

Lo que ofrecen estas librerías es un entorno que facilite la programación y evaluación de las pruebas... pero esta tarea no se realiza por arte de magia. Normalmente es necesario crear una aplicación de test, es decir, una aplicación cuyo único cometido es ejecutar una batería de test para verificar el correcto funcionamiento de una aplicación o de parte de ella.

¿Y cómo se integran estos test?

Pues depende de la librería que decidas utilizar. Cada una tiene sus ventajas y sus inconvenientes y cada una se integra y se usa de forma diferente... no obstante en Internet tienes multitud de enlaces a tutoriales y páginas de ayuda que te enseñan cómo usar cada una de las librerías.